# Prove $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac {1} {n\ln(n)\ln\ln{n}}$ is divergent.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, logarithms

> Evaluate if the following series is convergent or divergent: $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac {1} {n\ln(n)\ln\ln{n}}$.

I cannot properly understand the notation that the book employs here $\ln\ln(x)$, but I guess it is referring to $\ln(\ln(x))$. Assuming $\ln \ln(x)=\ln(\ln(x))$,

I used the Weierstrass's or comparasion test to evaluate the series:

$$\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac {1} {n\ln(n)\ln\ln{n}}<\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac {1} {n\ln(n)\ln(n)}=\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac {1} {n\ln^2{n}}<\sum_\limits{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2},$$ proving the series converge.
However the solution point out the series diverge.

I have already proved the convergence $\sum_\limits{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$.

**Question:**

What am I doing wrong? How can I prove the series diverge? Is $\ln\ln(x)=\ln(\ln(x))$ meant by the author of the book?

Comment: $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac {1} {n\times\ln(n)\times\ln\ln{n}}<\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac {1} {n\times\ln(n)\times\ln(n)}$

This is not good because $\ln(n) < n$ or $\ln(\ln(n))< \ln(n)$ so the reciprocal will be?

Comment: In the past few weeks, I saw a few similar questions to this question on Math.Stackexchange.  I guess next week I will see this question: Is this series convergent $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n\,\ln(n)\,\ln\big(\ln(n)\big)\,\ln\Big(\ln\big(\ln(n)\big)\Big)}\,?$$  Anyway, if $\ln^{[k]}$ denote the $k$-time iteration of $\ln$ (with $\ln^{[0]}$ being the identity map), then $$\sum_{r=2}^n\,\frac{1}{\prod\limits_{k=0}^m\,\ln^{[k]}(r)}\sim \ln^{[m+1]}(n)$$ for all integers $m\geq 0$ and $n\geq 2$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your series diverges by the integral test, because$$\int\frac1{x\log(x)\log\bigl(\log(x)\bigr)}\,\mathrm dx=\log\bigl(\log\bigl(\log(x)\bigr)\bigr)$$and because $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\log\bigl(\log\bigl(\log(x)\bigr)\bigr)=+\infty$.

Concerning your approach, note that the inequality $\frac1{n\ln^2n}<\frac1{n^2}$ is false. Actually, $n\ln^2n<n^2$.

Comment: Sir, which test you used? Is it Cauchy integral test?

Comment: No. As I wrote, I used the integral test.

Comment: You spelled "Actually" wrong.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

**HINT**

Let use [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test)

$$ 0 \ \leq\ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)\ \leq\ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{n}f(2^{n})\ \leq\ 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)$$

$$\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac {1} {n\ln(n)\ln\ln{n}}\ge \frac12\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac {2^n} {2^n\ln(2^n)\ln\ln{2^n}}=\frac12\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac {1} {n\ln 2\ln(n\ln 2)}$$

and

$$\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac {1} {n\ln 2\ln(n\ln 2)}\ge \frac12 \sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac {2^n} {2^n\ln 2\ln(2^n\ln 2)}=\frac12 \sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac {1} {\ln 2\cdot (n\ln 2+\ln \ln 2)}$$

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use Cauchy condensation test. It is usually a good option when there are logarithms. You have to use it twice here.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, use Ermakoff's test:
$$\lim_\limits{x\to\infty} \frac{e^xf(e^x)}{f(x)}=\lim_\limits{x\to\infty} \frac{e^x\cdot \frac{1}{e^x\cdot x\cdot \ln x}}{\frac{1}{x\cdot \ln x\cdot \ln \ln x}}=$$
$$\lim_\limits{x\to\infty} \ln \ln x=\infty.$$
Hence, the series diverges.